# iOS - How can I "Like/Share" any Photos of particular Page from my App with FBGraph API?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-like, fb-graph

I am using FBGraph API for integrating FaceBook to my iOS app, I want to "Like/Share" Photos from particular page's Photo Album or from friend's Photos Album. Is it possible? Can any one help me for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try This it may help for you.
in post action method write the following code to share photo.

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
NSURL *imageURL = [[NSURL alloc]  initWithString:@"http://track_images/images/20120209104734baby-puppy.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];    
FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];
[variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"117795728310/photos" withPostVars:variables];
NSString *res = fb_graph_response.htmlResponse;
NSLog(@"res>> %@",res);
NSRange wordRange = NSMakeRange(0,2);
NSArray *firstWords = [[res componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] subarrayWithRange:wordRange];

if (![[firstWords objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"error"]){
 //alert for image posted sucessfully. 
 }
 else{
 //alert for image not posted sucessfully.

}
```

Comment: Thanks murali but can you help me for **"Like"** functionality?

Comment: Try this:                                                     FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"117795728310/likes" withPostVars:variables];